# TYPO3 laterally border around "Grid Element"

Tags: html, css, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Actually I am creating a border around my website in TYPO3 (version 7.6.14). I am creating this whith three border pictures (one for top, one for bottom and one for the left and right side) and it still workes fine at "normal" pages.

Only the border for the left and right side is created by css and the two others in the template. The whole page is surroundet the div "website".

Now I added a "Grid Element" to the main page. This is also in the website div included. Only the border is not shown at the Grid Elements part and non of my tries workes.

My css code is the following one:

```
div#website {
    width:1200px;
    text-align:left;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url(images/border_lr.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:left;
}
```

I know that the pixel methode is not the best way, but it should not be the problem, I even changed this and tryed to resize the other content, but it did not helped. The border is not in the background, it is just not created at the Grid Elements part of the website.

Comment: without HTML, it is not possible to debug this issue.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to set up a fiddle or something for this. Your question is not dependent on typo3 btw, it looks more of a css-only related problem.

Comment: A fiddler won't help, because I know what it is doing (or not doing) but not how to solve it.

Okey, thank you, I will try it with HTML, but my problem there is, that the pages have only one template but different lengh. I may need a second template for this page, or would you actually have a better advice?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the :before and :after [pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)?